# Trouble accessing BQ Ubuntu Phone on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: usb, ubuntu-touch

I have the BQ Aquaris E4.5 Ubuntu Phone. For a class project, I need to perform a simple forensics analysis on it. However, I am having trouble accessing the device from a computer (both Ubuntu 14.04 and Windows 8.1).

[Ubuntu 1]: When I connect the phone to the computer, I don't see it from GUI listed anywhere, neither a message pops up telling me that USB device has just been connected. Please note that "Developer Mode" is enabled and the device is on and unlocked. From the terminal, I can see it listed with "dmesg"

```
[ 7998.286944] usb 3-4.4: USB disconnect, device number 27
[ 8001.193264] usb 3-4.4: new high-speed USB device number 28 using xhci_hcd
[ 8001.210064] usb 3-4.4: New USB device found, idVendor=2a47, idProduct=0c02
[ 8001.210069] usb 3-4.4: New USB device strings: Mfr=2, Product=3, SerialNumber=4
[ 8001.210071] usb 3-4.4: Product: Aquaris_E4.5
[ 8001.210074] usb 3-4.4: Manufacturer: BQ
[ 8001.210076] usb 3-4.4: SerialNumber: JU010909
```

and with `adb devices`

```
$ adb devices
List of devices attached 
JU010909    device
```

the system info from `adb`

```
current build number: 21
device name: krillin
channel: ubuntu-touch/stable/bq-aquaris.en
alias: ubuntu-touch/ubuntu-rtm/14.09
last update: 2015-03-24 17:41:19
version version: 21
version ubuntu: 20150410.1
version device: 20150408-4f14058
version custom: 20150409-665-29-206
```

With `lsusb` (after connecting and disconnecting the device, I narrowed it down to this entry (which doesn't show a device description)

```
Bus 003 Device 029: ID 2a47:0c02
```

The problem is that I still can't access the device from anywhere or find it.

[Ubuntu 2]: On a different computer (also running Ubuntu 14.04), the device is accessible from the GUI, but the only directories that are shown are "Documents, Downloads, Music, Pictures, Videos". With the "Developer Mode" enabled, I still see the same directories and have no way of accessing the filesystem. From a terminal, I still only see the same directories and still can't access the filesystem. It is shown as an "mtp" device, but from what I know (and please correct me if I am wrong), the filesystem will not be accessible if the device is in Media Transfer Protocol.

What I want to do is be able to take an image of the device that I can later go through with FTK or EnCase or something similar and be able to find data that I have put in the device.

[Windows]: When I connect the phone to a Windows 8.1 computer, I am able to see the same directories as listed above. I am still not able to access the filesystem. However, the problem is that the ADB drivers (which I got from the vendor's official website http://www.mibqyyo.com/descargas/2013/11/25/drivers-y-utilidades/ ) for the device are not working and cannot be installed. Therefore, I can't access the device with FTK or EnCase and can't take an image of it.

In conclusion, I would like to have access to the phone's filesystem, be able to take an image of it and perform a forensics analysis on it. I hope someone can help me with this. Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Have you considered connecting via SSH and using dd?

Comment: This will be the next thing I try. I hope it will work out for me. I will update the post either way.

Comment: [Update]: I tried to connect to it over SSH, but even though I pushed my key to the phone it won't allow me to connect to it. However I can SSH from the phone to my Ubuntu desktop. It's very strange...